Cloud Code extension for VS Code: How do I configure the "client-name" to avoid the error "Failed to deploy the app. Error: undefined"?
When I try to deploy using the UI, this is what's running in the background:

Running gcloud command: run deploy xxx --project xxx --image gcr.io/xxx/xxx --client-name Cloud Code for VS Code --client-version 2.20.2 --platform managed --region us-central1 --allow-unauthenticated --port 8080 --cpu 1 --memory 256Mi --concurrency 80 --timeout 300 --clear-env-vars

However, as you can see, "Cloud Code for VS Code" has no quotes, and for this reason, the deploy fails:

Failed to deploy the app. Error: undefined


Cloud Run API check failed. Requests will be rejected after January 2025 hard enforcement deadline. User does not have access to image gcr.io/xxx/xxx

Where in the extension can I change the client name?

Hi rioV8 this is not the reason the deployment failed.  While there are no quotes the extension doesn't deploy using shell so the commands not being quoted is irrelevant.  Your log would be helpful.

Are you sure, Keith? When I deploy using the extension, the message "Running gcloud command: run deploy..." appears, so I believe it’s calling gcloud. Otherwise, can you explain it?
Copying the command and adding the quotes solves the issue. I didn’t find anything relevant in the log, but I’ll paste it here next time.

Log: "Cloud Run API check failed. Requests will be rejected after January 2025 hard enforcement deadline. User does not have access to image gcr.io/xxx/xxx"

Here are the workarounds you can follow to address the issue:

Cloud Code Extension Version

Make sure that you are using the correct version or updated version of the Cloud Code extension for VS code. Sometimes bugs like this are fixed in updates.


Run a Custom Deployment Command using terminal or CLI

Add a quote around the –client-name value:

gcloud run deploy xxx --project xxx --image gcr.io/xxx/xxx --client-name "Cloud Code for VS Code" --client-version 2.20.2 --platform managed --region us-central1 --allow-unauthenticated --port 8080 --cpu 1 --memory 256Mi --concurrency 80 --timeout 300 --clear-env-vars


Adjust Cloud Code settings in VS Code


Open your project in VS Code.

Go to File > Preferences > Settings (or use Ctrl+,).

Search for Cloud Code: Deploy in the settings.

If there is no explicit setting for the --client-name, modify the deployment pipeline in your configuration.





Of course, there are workarounds, but you’re not really answering my question, which is what truly matters here.
